# Generics with inner class and comparision

Tags: java, generics

I am not very good with generics in java. I am getting confused over how to deal with generics when an inner class exists. Below code to implement Binary Search Tree gives me an error.

```
public class BST <T extends Comparable<T>>
{
  Node<T> root;

 private class Node<T extends Comparable<T>>
   {
    T data;
    Node<T> left, right;

    Node(T data)
     {
      this.data = data;
      left= right = null;    
     }

   }

  public void insert(Node<T> start, T data)
   {     
     if(start == null) 
           { 
            Node<T> newnode = new Node<T> (data);          
            start = newnode;
            return;
            }

     else if( data < start.data )   //ERROR LINE
                insert(start.left, data);
     else if ( data > start.data )   //ERROR LINE               
                insert(start.right, data);

     else 
       {
           //no need to do anything as the elements has the same key as the new key
          return;
      }
   }
```

**Error:**

```
BST.java:29: error: bad operand types for binary operator '<'
     else if( data < start.data )
 first type:  T  second type: T  where T is a type-variable: T extends Comparable<T> declared in class BST.
```

Comment: data.compareTo(start.data) < 0

Comment: Why don't you make the inner class static? Do you need the reference to BST.this.root?

Comment: I have got over it David. I came to know that we have to use compareTo method in this case. I am not sure about the implications of static class in this context. Thanks very much.

Comment: for best results use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any object extending Comparable does not automatically give it support over the numerical comparison operators but rather the `compareTo()` method which specifies:

> Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

So using something like:

```
data.compareTo(start.data) < 0
```

should do the trick.